# Die Verwendung des Tätigkeitswortes "brabbeln" zur Beschreibung eines Erwachsenen, der ein Baby nachahmt?

Tags: word-usage, verb

> Der Vater brabbelt mit dem Baby.

Kann man das Verb "brabbeln" zur Beschreibung eines Erwachsenen, der das Baby nachahmt, verwenden? Oder kann man "sprechen" benutzen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich würde das so verwenden, schließlich ahmt der Erwachsene die Laute des Kleinkindes nach, und diese wiederum werden ja auch korrekt als [Brabbeln](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanonisches_Lallen) bezeichnet.

Comment: Kann man das Verb ratschen benützen?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33... nie gehört. Ist auf jeden Fall was Regionales also lieber Finger weg.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 ich kenne *ratschen* nur als Synonym zu *tratschen* und *klatschen* - hat in dieser Bedeutung nichts mit Babysprache zu tun.