# Mit welchem Verb kann man beschreiben, wie Erwachsene mit einem Baby sprechen?

Tags: vocabulary

Ich habe zu dem Thema diese Frage gefunden: [Die Verwendung des Tätigkeitswortes "brabbeln" zur Beschreibung eines Erwachsenen, der ein Baby nachahmt?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9865/die-verwendung-des-t%c3%a4tigkeitswortes-brabbeln-zur-beschreibung-eines-erwachsene)

Aber, ganz ehrlich, Brabbeln kenne ich bisher nur zur Beschreibung des Kindes, das unverständliche Laute von sich gibt. Das trifft meines Erachtens auf die Erwachsenen ja eher nicht zu. Da ist die Sprache zwar radikal verniedlicht und um eine Oktave erhöht, aber als unverständliches "Brabbeln" würde ich es trotzdem eher nicht bezeichnen.

Vielleicht eher Plappern?

Gibt es da noch andere Begriffe?

Beispielsatz:

> Sie war damit beschäftigt, mit ihrem Baby zu ...

Oder:

> Sie war damit beschäftigt, ihr Baby anzu...

Comment: Kannst Du vielleicht einen Beispielsatz angeben, damit man erkennt, wie Du das Verb verwenden möchtest?

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort der gefundenen Frage ausreichend: die Erwachsenen sprechen mit dem Baby in seiner Art & Weise: und das ist Brabbeln. Oder babbeln.

Comment: Hier wird explizit gefragt, ob es andere Begriffe als *brabbeln* gibt, und ihr wollt das als Duplikat einer Frage werten, in der es ausschließlich um *brabbeln* geht?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich lese im Duplikat "Ist brabbeln iO oder was anderes wie sprechen?". Daher: Ja, es wird hier nach was anderem gefragt, das nicht brabbeln ist. Doch das ist bei der anderen Frage m.E. auch nicht ausgeschlossen / es ist da lediglich der Aufhänger.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Der Fragesteller findet dort aber nur *brabbeln*, womit ihm nicht geholfen ist.

Comment: Ich biete *kieksen*.

Comment: Kein Verb, aber es gibt "in Babysprache reden/sprechen/..."

Comment: Im Allgemeinen kann man das Sprechen in einer höheren Tonart als "flöten" bezeichnen. Beispiel: "Du bist aber ein süßes Ding, Duzi Duzi" flötete er am Kinderwagen...

Comment: @Allerleirauh "Flöten" passt super. :D

Answer (score 5):

Brabbeln, babeln, usw. bezieht sich primär darauf, wie das "Sprechen" des Babys umgangssprachlich bezeichnet wird. Das Baby lernt damit seine Sprechwerkzeuge zu benutzen und macht auf sich aufmerksam, aber weiß nicht, dass damit Information ausgetauscht wird. Eine reine Nachahmung dieser Geräuschproduktion kann umgangssprachlich mit den selben Verben bezeichnet werden. Oder man umschreibt es mit "in Babysprache reden".

Eine inhaltliche Kommunikation des Erwachsenen mit dem Kind ist mit diesen Verben aber nicht gemeint. Für diese baby- oder kindgerechte Form der Sprache, wenn der Erwachsene seine Stimme hebt und in stark vereinfachter Form spricht (auch unter Verwendung von Wörtern der Kleinkindsprache), gibt es kein extra Verb.

Comment: alternativ ginge noch "Babylaute machen". Je nachdem wie alt das Kind ist und wie man reden definiert ^^

Answer (score 1):

Ein eigentliches Verb für diese Art, wie Erwachsene bisweilen mit Babies sprechen (erhöhte Stimmlage, betonte emotionale Expressivität, reduziertes Vokabular, einfache Syntax), sehe ich nicht. Es gibt jedoch einen lautmalerischen Ausdruck, mit dem man gemeinhin diese Art verbaler Zuwendung zum Baby-Gegenüber markiert:

> Dutzi-dutzi-dutzi...

Nicht unwichtig fürs Gesamtbild ist die zughörige Physiognomie mit gespitzen Lippen (was im angloamerikansichen Sprachraum heute oft *duck face* heißt) und hervorqellenden Augen.

Das lässt sich nun nicht gut in eine elaboriertere Sprachform einbauen wie eine Parlamentsrede oder einen wissenschaftlichen Aufsatz, aber es ist im Alltag das gängige Mittel, diese Kommunikationsform zu vergegenwärtigen. Vorstellen kann ich mir auch eine Verwendung in einem Roman oder einer Erzählung:

> ... wandte sich die Tante dem im Korb liegenden Baby zu und machte "dutzi-dutzi-dutzi". Das Baby reagierte mit fröhlichem Glucksen.

Demnach könnte man vielleicht behaupten, dass ***dutzi-dutzi machen*** ein Verb bzw. ein geeigneter verbaler Ausdruck ist.

Answer (score 0):

Im Allgemeinen kann man das Sprechen in einer höheren Tonart als "flöten" bezeichnen.

Beispiel: "Du bist aber ein süßes Ding, Duzi Duzi" flötete er am Kinderwagen...

Laut duden.de :

> "flöten"
>
> Bedeutungen (2):
>
> 1
>
> a) [laienhaft] Flöte (1) spielen; 
>   Gebrauch selten
>
> b)
>   Töne hervorbringen, die wie Flötentöne klingen
>
> Beispiel-die Amsel flötete
>
> c)
>   pfeifen; 
>   Gebrauch landschaftlich
>
> 2
>
> a)
>   mit einschmeichelnder, hoher Stimme sprechen
>
> b)
>   flötend (2a) sagen
>
> Beispiel-„Die Freude ist ganz meinerseits“, flötete sie